# How do I enter proxy information in odbc.ini file in Linux?

Tags: linux, proxy, odbc, amazon-redshift

I'm configuring a DSN for connecting to Amazon Redshift from my Linux machine. Since the machine is behind firewall, I need to use proxy for connecting to my redshift cluster.

In Windows, while creating DSN I was able to enter http proxy information in the dialog box (as in the pic below), so the connection was successful.

[Dialog box in Windows asking for Proxy Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSfKR.png)

But in Linux, I'm not sure how to enter the proxy information in odbc.ini. I'm not able to connect because the driver manager is not picking the proxy info.

I'm using Amazon ODBC driver for redshift and even their documentation here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/odbc-driver-configure-linux-mac.html does not show proxy configuration. I tried setting attributes like ProxyHost and ProxyPort but it doesn't help. Can someone please guide me here? Thanks!

Comment: How did you enter the proxy information in the dialog box? If you can fill me in on that, I can likely tell you the associated .ini file settings to use.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I've edited the question with the image of the dialog box.

Comment: Hmm, ProxyHost and ProxyPort are the two required keys for enabling proxy settings, let me investigate and see if I can find anything. Ping me here if you haven't heard in a few days.

Comment: Are you able to make a connection directly without the proxy? I've tested this and it seems to work as expected when the two keys are present in the DSN.